# Do translated taxonomy terms have different tid's?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

As per title; or are they translated in the same way user interface elements are handled?
Im using Drupal 7 btw.

Answer (score 1):

No if you choose to localize your terms. Edit your vocabulary and tick this option: "Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized."